# Appending key value in co-occurence

Tags: python, collections, key, append, frequency

I have a corpus of text : from a file containing various sentences and paragraphs

here is my code:

```
import re
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
import math
from collections import Counter
with open("descriptionsample.tsv", "r") as openfile:
frequency = Counter()
stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer("[\w’]+", flags=re.UNICODE)
for line in openfile:
    words = line.lower().strip()
    words=re.sub(r'[0-9]|\~|\`|\@|\#|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\(|\)|\_|\+|\=|\{|\[|\}|\]|\\|\<|\,|\<|\.|\>|\?|\/|\;|\:', '',words).replace('-',' ')
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(words)
    tokens = [token for token in tokens if token not in stopwords]
    frequency.update(tokens)
```

my results are in a Counter format

```
{'code':32344,'sql':2123,'chicago':1233...........} etc.
```

but suppose the result of performing the word frequency by the very first line of the document is:

```
{'code':10,'sql':3,'python':2........}
```

What I'm trying to do is create a co-occurrence matrix out of tuples by document (as opposed to bi-grams/tri-grams ect.), then collect the sums at the very end. Essentially appending the count of each key to a newly created tuple made from Key1,Key2:Value of Key2. Where key2 can even be key1.

So after counting the word frequency in each line of the tsv file, I want the by line result to look something like this:

```
{('code','code'):10,('code','sql)':3,('code','python'):2,('sql,'code'):10,('sql','sql'):3,('sql','python'):2,('python','code'):10,('python','sql'):3,('python','python'):2}
```

I can't figure it out. Any help? Maybe I'm overlooking some other library out there that would do this it self.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague figured it out for me. I had initially tried layers and layers of nested dictionaries, but traversing through it would have been a nightmare. Thus, this is a much simpler and more efficient of solving my problem:

```
doc2= {
'a': 1,
'b': 2,
'c': 3,
'd': 4,
'e': 5
}

res = {}

for key1 in doc2.keys():
    for key2 in doc2.keys():
        if key1 != key2:
            res[(key1, key2)] = doc2[key2]


for key in res:
    print("[{}, {}] = {}".format(key[0], key[1], res[key]))
```

Result:

```
[b, c] = 3
[d, a] = 1
[b, a] = 1
[d, c] = 3
[e, d] = 4
[c, d] = 4
[d, e] = 5
[c, e] = 5
[e, c] = 3
[c, a] = 1
[a, d] = 4
[e, b] = 2
[a, e] = 5
[d, b] = 2
[c, b] = 2
[a, b] = 2
[e, a] = 1
[b, e] = 5
[a, c] = 3
[b, d] = 4
```